# nslookup failures *** UnKnown can't find www.vmware.com: Query refused

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation, nslookup

I am on a VMware environment. On the host machine I do

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>nslookup www.vmware.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  109.169.85.7

*** UnKnown can't find www.vmware.com: Query refused
```

but I can access the site in browser. 
Every thing is working fine perfectly.
I have this question because my virtual machines can not access internet and when I do ping from a VM to host I can ping and get reply.
ping from virtual machine to host os  is following

```
C:\Users\Debian>ping 192.168.1.14

Pinging 192.168.1.14 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.14: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.14: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.14: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.14: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.14:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 3ms, Average = 1ms
```

nslookup on  virtual machine

```
C:\Users\Debian>nslookup www.vmware.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.136.2

*** UnKnown can't find www.vmware.com: Query refused
```

so in both the situations I have similar outout of nslookup Query refused. But there is a difference in the output as on host machine I get the ip address.
So what I want to know is what is the default nslookup behaviour what is the mistake I have on my host os.
the ip configurations at host OS

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.name
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.14
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

on virtual machine

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet0:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.136.128
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.136.2
```

the output of route print on virtual machine

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 12...00 0c 29 fb 2a 71 ......Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.136.2  192.168.136.128     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
    192.168.136.0    255.255.255.0         On-link   192.168.136.128    281
  192.168.136.128  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.136.128    281
  192.168.136.255  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.136.128    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link   192.168.136.128    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.136.128    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

output of route print on host OS

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 25...18 60 24 13 ea a4 ......Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller #2
  2...00 50 56 c0 00 01 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
 16...00 50 56 c0 00 08 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
 12...0c b6 d2 cf 9e b1 ......D-Link DWA-131 Wireless N Nano USB Adapter(rev.E)
 14...f8 da 0c 50 44 91 ......Realtek RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.14     50
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.14    306
     192.168.1.14  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.14    306
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.14    306
     192.168.56.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    291
     192.168.56.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    291
   192.168.56.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    291
    192.168.136.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.136.1    291
    192.168.136.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.136.1    291
  192.168.136.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.136.1    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.14    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.136.1    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.14    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.136.1    291
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

here is screenshot of virtual network editor on host machine
[image: virtual network editor]
and network adaptor configuration on virtual machine
 [image: network adapter configuration on vm]

since my virtual machines are not connected to internet and I am using NAT configuration in vmnet so I want to understand where is the problem in nslookup output.

**update 1**
here is the output of 
here is an output of nslookup from virtual machine when I do

C:\Users\Debian>nslookup www.vmware.com

```
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.136.2
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out
```

nslookup www.vmware.com 192.168.1.1

```
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1
Name:    e751.dscx.akamaiedge.net
Addresses:  2600:1417:2c:194::2ef
   2600:1417:2c:1a8::2ef
   104.114.87.171
Aliases:  www.vmware.com
   www.vmware.com.ds.edgekey.net
```

nslookup www.vmware.com 8.8.8.8

```
Server:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8
Name:    e751.dscx.akamaiedge.net
Addresses:  2600:1417:2c:194::2ef
   2600:1417:2c:1a8::2ef
   104.114.87.171
Aliases:  www.vmware.com
   www.vmware.com.ds.edgekey.net
```

[image: nslookup 3 different ways]
 192.168.1.1 is my ADSL router DHCP and DNS I get my broadband connection from there.
The configuration of DNS settings of my ADSL router looks as follows
[image: adsl router dns settings configuration]
Basically there is no internet connectivity in virtual machines.

Comment: check with nslookup vmware.com 192.168.1.1 or other public dns first

Comment: ok I did that and updated the outputs below **update 1** in question added a screenshot. Basically the problem is virtual machines do not have internet connectivity.

Comment: you really run the command from inside the vm? if yes then you have working internet but your dns Resolution is broken

Comment: Yes that command was run from within VM as far as DNS resolution is concerned I posted a screenshot of my ADSL router login page.

Comment: i cant see any Screenshots. however try to chsmge the default dns server to 192.168.1.1 and try thrm to do a nslookup and maybe a ping

Comment: all these are present in post above but since my reputation is less than 10 so it
is not displayed these are inline in the text of question
giving you links exclusively to view these
virtual network editor  
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsPFm.jpg
network adapter configuration
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Upkqs.jpg
nslookup 3 different ways
https://i.stack.imgur.com/185pW.jpg
adsl router dns configurations
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h05Cb.jpg

dns setting in virtual network editor or network adapter of vm
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I-kCJTD463yyCReH74PJL_acPQvEzF2k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: uncheck detect and set them manually

Comment: Thanks a lot this has worked.ns look up in vm after dns change
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZO2VioostBNYulgn6BT4aqf0C4lQ6yp0/view?usp=sharing

dns settings in virtual network editor changed in vmnet8 
to my ADSL router
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1laKbiMZAKnNxGS8mFuySZAmyKTin3Yds/view?usp=sharing

previous DNS setting was automatic which can be seen in this screenshot 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I-kCJTD463yyCReH74PJL_acPQvEzF2k/view

ipconfig on host OS
https://drive.google.com/file/d/153QZmFm3hv9rNTrUouQ6RWrZ2nRhMUv8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: working internet screenshot in virtual machine google in virtual machine
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SI2rhflir47II2DYk4g4sNvqjUXwLSDn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: but nslookup on virtual machine has still failed I want to dig more into it as why it is failing.

Comment: as i see you currently using double nat, try to change the way how it connect. did you change the dns manuallyon the vm?

Comment: to be clear what i tried to tell you; first eliminate the double nat. set the Adress of the vm with your default lan ip range, use the dsl modem as dns server and the resulution should work as already tested above. it seems that the vmware dns not working correctly.